# Employee, Departments, and ManagerID Table Structures

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, constraints

In MS SQL, I have employees and departments tables. I need remodel the tables to allow me to assign department managers.

**Here are the existing tables:**

```
Employee 
---------
emp_id
emp_name 
emp_email
Dept_id


Departments 
-----------
Dept_id
Dept_name
```

The rules I have are as follows:

- A dept manager is an existing employee who is already in the emp
  table.
- Employee can only be assigned to one department.
- A department may not have a manager.

What new fields and constraints do I need to add?

Knowing that a manager is an employee as I indicated.
What SQL Query can I use to list department name, managers-name, manager-extension,manager-email for all departments with a manager assigned?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a third table:

```
DepartmentManagers 
-----------
Dept_id
emp_id
```

Of course, you'd have to also add those other fields you mention, either to the Employee table if you want that data (extension, etc.) or to the DepartmentManagers table if you don't need it for non-Managers. Department Name would logically belong in the  then you could query it with something like (pseudoSQL):

```
SELECT E.emp_name, E.email, E.extension, E.email, D.Dept_name FROM EMPLOYEE E, DEPARTMENTS D, DEPARTMENTMANAGERS M WHERE E.emp_id = M.emp_id AND D.Dept_id = M.Dept_id
```

Another option would be to add an "IsManager" field to the Employee table; in that case, you wouldn't need the third table.

Then the query would be more like (pseudoSQL, especially because there may not be a boolen type; you might have to use 1 instead of TRUE):

```
SELECT E.emp_name, E.email, E.extension, E.email, D.Dept_name FROM EMPLOYEE E, Departments D WHERE E.Dept_id = D.Dept_id AND E.IsManager = TRUE
```

Comment: That looks neat. I just did that and it works nicely. Thanks
Can you help me with constraints too please? How do I create one that ensures that new records (IDs) in this new table exist in both tables (Emp) and (Dept).

Comment: You could enforce RI (Referential Integrity) here in one of two ways: either declaratively, by making Dept_id and _emp_Id in the DepartmentManagers table FK (Foreign Keys) pointing to the primary keys in those other two tables, OR you could enforce it with a SP (Stored Procedure) for the DepartmentManagers table, specifically on OnInsert SP that would verify that the values existed in the respective tables before making the Insert there.

Comment: Besides checking that the IDs about to be inserted exist in their respective tables, you may also need to check that they don't already exist in the DepartmentManagers table (unless you want to allow more than one manager per department). You can do this by declaring the IDs Unique.

Comment: Well, I resorted to using "IsManager" as it is a more straight forward solution using your query. Thanks again.